# MySql group by and order by different column

Tags: mysql

I have a table and I wanted to group by one column and get all values with order by date and time column.

```
**My table**
-------------------------------
id | name | created_at
===+======+===========
1  | a    | 2020-11-18 04:33:55
2  | b    | 2020-11-14 10:17:28
3  | c    | 2020-11-12 20:26:00
4  | a    | 2020-11-11 18:35:24
5  | c    | 2020-11-10 10:55:04
```

---

```
**Result**
-------------------------------
id | name | created_at
===+======+===========
1  | a    | 2020-11-18 04:33:55
2  | b    | 2020-11-14 10:17:28
3  | c    | 2020-11-12 20:26:00
```

In the older version of Mysql(V. 5.7.32) the below query is working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` GROUP BY name ORDER by created_at DESC
```

But in the new version of mysql(V. 8.0.22) the below code is not working.
Please anyone have a solution for it.

Comment: *the below query is working fine.* It is random - the query is non-deterministic. if you get correct output then you're lucky.

Comment: We have very different understandings of the term 'fine'. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, but be aware that this is the most frequently asked question under this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
         FROM my_table )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I got the result as accepted. Can you please tell me why they have removed this feature in the new version? (for my better understanding).

Comment: @Nashir *why they have removed this feature in the new version?* ?? As I have said in a comment to the question - your query provided in the question text is wrong. You may ensure - simply set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode, and your query will fail on your 5.7.32. Or backward - disable this mode in 8.0.22, and the query will work (but again it will give unpredictable output).

Comment: Yes, there is an option to disable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode, after disable i can able to use my old code. @Akina Thanks.

Using this cmd I can disable 
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: @Nashir ... and you continue to use wrong query? this is your choice... do not be surprised if somewhen it will start to return incorrect output.